# Access SQL query to SELECT from one table and INSERT into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Below is my query.  Access does not like it, giving me the error `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'answer WHERE question = 1'.`

Hopefully you can see what I am trying to do.  Please pay particular attention to 3rd, 4th, and 5th lines under the `SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (respondent,1,2,3-1,3-2,3-3,4,5)
SELECT respondent,
answer WHERE question = 1,
answer WHERE question = 2,
answer WHERE answer = 'text 1' AND question = 3,
answer WHERE answer = 'text 2' AND question = 3,
answer WHERE answer = 'text 3' AND question = 3,
answer WHERE question = 4,
longanswer WHERE question 5 FROM Table1 GROUP BY respondent;
```

**UPDATE:**

I have made a little progress with this, but I still cannot get my data in the format I really want.  I used several `Iif` statements to get as far as I am now, but `GROUP BY` simply isn't working the way I would expect it to.  I have also tried variations on my `SELECT` statement (like `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT` and `TRANSFORM`) but I guess I am not using them correctly because I always get errors.  Here is what my data looks like now:

[image]

All I need to do now is smash all the similar `respondent` rows together (that is, `respondent` rows that have the same number) so all the cells that are empty are removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this all sorted out.  I was on the right track for a long time, but just wasn't getting it exactly right.  After removing some unneeded columns and performing some significant formatting I was able to run the following query to produce the results I needed.  Thanks for all your suggestions.

```
TRANSFORM Max(Sheet1.[answer]) AS MaxOfanswer
SELECT Sheet1.[respondent], Max(Sheet1.[answer]) AS [Total Of answer]
FROM Sheet1
GROUP BY Sheet1.[respondent]
PIVOT Sheet1.[question];
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for**

I think what you want to do is this (you can't have WHERE in the SELECT section):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (respondent,1,2,3-1,3-2,3-3,4,5)
SELECT respondent,
Iif(question = 1, answer, 0),
Iif(question = 2, answer, 0),
Iif(answer = 'text 1' AND question = 3, answer, 0),
Iif(answer = 'text 2' AND question = 3, answer, 0),
Iif(answer = 'text 3' AND question = 3, answer, 0),
Iif(question = 4, answer)
Iif(question 5 NOT IS NULL, longanswer)
FROM Table1 GROUP BY respondent;
```

I think the question 5 one will work but not totally sure, I think that's correct.

You should be able to replace the 0 with NULL if that's what you prefer.

Comment: I get the error `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'IIf(question = 1,answer,0)' as part of an aggregate function.`  Not sure what that means...

Comment: I found that the `GROUP BY` statement is what is causing my error.  Not sure why it is though.

Comment: Unlike MySQL, in Access and SQL Server to use GROUP BY you must have an aggregate function - and there is no aggregate function in this query (examples: SUM(respondent), COUNT(respondent), etc.).  If you found a suitable aggregate function for respondent, then you would have to include all the other Iif statements in the Group By clause.

Comment: "Access and SQL Server to use GROUP BY you must have an aggregate function" -- incorrect, this is not a requirement in either of those products e.g. `SELECT c FROM T GROUP BY c;` is valid and an oft used  alternative to `SELECT DISTINCT c FROM T;`

Comment: "Oft-used"? I've never seen such a thing as an alternative to DISTINCT. Does `SELECT c, d FROM T GROUP BY c;` work? That would be the more comparable example, seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

The way you "smash all the similar respondent rows together (that is, respondent rows that have the same number) so all the cells that are empty are removed" is simple: you use GROUP BY.

Assuming (you haven't given us the schema) that the schema for your source table looks something like this:

```
create table response
(
  respondent_id int          not null , -- PK.1 respondent
  question_id   int          not null , -- PK.2 question number
  answer        varchar(200)     null ,

  primary key clustered ( respondent_id , question_id ) ,

)
```

which is to say that each respondent has at most one response to a particular question, then your select statement to get the desired result set will look something like this (in Transact-SQL -- Access SQL will look somewhat different:

```
select respondent_id = t.respondent_id ,
       q1            = max( q1.answer  ) ,
       q2            = max( q2.answer  ) ,
       q3a           = max( q3a.answer ) ,
       q3b           = max( q3b.answer ) ,
       q3c           = max( q3c.answer ) ,
       q4            = max( q4.answer  ) ,
       q5            = max( q5.answer  )
from ( select distinct respondent_id from response ) t
left join response q1  on q1.respondent_id  = t.respondent_id and q1.question_id  = 1
left join response q2  on q2.respondent_id  = t.respondent_id and q2.question_id  = 2
left join response q3a on q3a.respondent_id = t.respondent_id and q3a.question_id = 3 and q3a.answer = 'q3a answer'
left join response q3b on q3b.respondent_id = t.respondent_id and q3b.question_id = 3 and q3b.answer = 'q3b answer'
left join response q3c on q3c.respondent_id = t.respondent_id and q3c.question_id = 3 and q3c.answer = 'q3c answer'
left join response q4  on q4.respondent_id  = t.respondent_id and q4.question_id  = 4
left join response q5  on q5.respondent_id  = t.respondent_id and q5.question_id  = 5
group by t.respondent_id
```

You could also do it with a single table in the FROM clause, thus:

```
select respondent_id = t.respondent_id ,
       q1            = max( case t.question_id when 1 then t.answer else null end ) ,
       q2            = max( case t.question_id when 2 then t.answer else null end ) ,
       q3a           = max( case when t.question_id = 3 and t.answer = 'q3a answer' then t.answer else null end ) ,
       q3b           = max( case when t.question_id = 3 and t.answer = 'q3b answer' then t.answer else null end ) ,
       q3c           = max( case when t.question_id = 3 and t.answer = 'q3c answer' then t.answer else null end ) ,
       q4            = max( case t.question_id when 4 then t.answer else null end ) ,
       q5            = max( case t.question_id when 5 then t.answer else null end )
from response t
group by t.respondent_id
```